# VNC on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS not showing menu bar

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-x-session

I want to configure a VNC connection to a PC running Ubuntu. I am using vnc4server and the following ~/.vnc/xstartup script. However, the menu bar does not show and opening a terminal ist not possible. How can I fix this?

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
#/etc/X11/Xsession
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:GNOME"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
gnome-flashback &
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTgSU.png)